# Prove $\sum^n x_i^{m+1} \sum^n x_i^{-1} \ge n \sum^n x_i^m$ using Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> $$\sum \limits^n x_i^{m+1} \sum^n x_i^{-1} \ge n \sum^n x_i^m$$

This is an exercise for Cauchy-Schwarz, and it came after an exercise asking to prove that, for an arithmetic sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$, it holds that
$$\sum^n x_i^{a_1} \sum^n x_i^{a_4} \ge \sum^n x_i^{a_2} \sum^n x_i^{a_3},$$
which can be proved by multiplying CS inequalities with sequences of $x^{a_1},x^{a_3}$ and $x^{a_2},x^{a_3}$ so that squares and extra terms and squares cancel. There is also an exercise which is just an application of CS:

> $$\sum x^{k+1} \sum x^{k - 1} \ge \left( \sum x^k \right)^2$$

Having said that, I don't know how to solve the exercise from the title. Since there is no square on the RHS, I guess it is also solved by multiplying some CS inequalities, but I couldn't come up with anything that cancels out nicely. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all $x_i$'s assumed to be positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all of the ideas needed for the proof, so figure out how to use them.

Hint: $ n = \sum x_i ^ 0 $.

Further hint: Notice that $-1, 0, \ldots, m, m+1$ are also in an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve it with your hint. I also had thoughts about $-1, 0, \dots, m+1$ forming an arithmetic progression, but didn't give them too much attention.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all $x_i$'s are positive, we have for any $1\le i<j\le n$:
$$
x_i^{m+1}x_j^{-1}+x_j^{m+1}x_i^{-1}-x_i^m-x_j^m=(x_i^{m+1}-x_j^{m+1})(x_j^{-1}-x_i^{-1})=\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2}{x_i x_j}\sum_{k=0}^{m}{x_i^k x_j^{m-k}}\ge 0.
$$
For $1\le i=j\le n$, we simply get $x_i^{m+1}x_i^{-1}-x_i^m=0$.
Summing this over all pairs $(i,j)$, where $1\le i\le j\le n$, we get $\mathrm{LHS}-\mathrm{RHS}\ge 0$ for your inequality, since each $x_i^m$ is subtracted $n$ times: once for each $j<i$, once for $j=i$, and once for each $j>i$.

In fact, given integers $a_1<a_2\le a_3<a_4$ such that $a_1+a_4=a_2+a_3$, let $a_2-a_1=a_4-a_3=r\ge 1$ and $a_3-a_1=a_4-a_2=s\ge 1$, then we have
$$
\begin{split}
x_i^{a_1}x_j^{a_4}+x_j^{a_1}x_i^{a_4}-x_i^{a_2}x_j^{a_3}-x_j^{a_2}x_i^{a_3}&=x_i^{a_1}x_j^{a_1}(x_j^{r+s}+x_i^{r+s}-x_i^{r}x_j^{s}-x_i^{s}x_j^{r})\\
&=x_i^{a_1}x_j^{a_1}(x_i^r-x_j^r)(x_i^s-x_j^s)\\
&=x_i^{a_1}x_j^{a_1}(x_i-x_j)^2\left(\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}{x_i^k x_j^{r-1-k}}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}{x_i^k x_j^{s-1-k}}\right)\ge 0,
\end{split}
$$
so the proof proceeds as in the previous example with $r=1$, $s=m+1$, $a_1=-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I like the approach. However, I think the inequality should be true without the assumption that numbers are positive.

Comment: @YN Assuming all $x_i$'s are negative and $m$ is odd reverses the sign of the inequality in the answer, so the opposite inequality holds.

Comment: @YN You do need positivity, so please check the question phrasing again. Recall that CS is  $ \sum a_i ^2 \sum b_i^2 \geq ( \sum a_i b_i)^2$, so the terms on the LHS are positive.